# Inferring BRAM with unused addresses efficiently

Tags: vhdl, fpga

What is a correct way to infer a RAM with some unused higher addresses (using block RAMs)?
Using the code below (default values for generics, Xilinx synth and map) I get a RAM sized the same as if depth was set to `2**ADDRWIDTH`:

```
entity foo is
    generic (
        DATAWIDTH : positive := 8;
        DATADEPTH : positive := 5000;
        ADDRWIDTH : positive := 13
    );
    port (
        clk_a  : in std_logic;
        we_a   : in std_logic;
        addr_a : in std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTH-1 downto 0);
        di_a   : in std_logic_vector(DATAWIDTH-1 downto 0);
        do_a   : out std_logic_vector(DATAWIDTH-1 downto 0)
    );
end foo;

architecture bar of foo is
    type myram_type is array (DATADEPTH-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(DATAWIDTH-1 downto 0); --! type for ram content
    shared variable myram : myram_type; --! ram
begin
    process (clk_a)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_a) then
            if we_a = '1' then
                myram(conv_integer(addr_a)) := di_a;
            end if;
            do_a <= myram(conv_integer(addr_a));
        end if;
    end process;
end bar;
```

For example, I want a RAM with `DATAWIDTH = 8` and `DATADEPTH = 5000`, so the address has to be `ADDRWIDTH = 13` because `ADDRWIDTH = 12`would only allow to address 4096 RAM locations. Lets assume one block RAM ressource on my FPGA can hold 8192 bits.
If I handcoded this I required 5000*8/8192 rounded upwards = 5 block RAM ressources.
However, with the code above, synthesis and map of Xilinx results in 8 block RAM ressources being used, because thats what can be addressed by 13 bit wide addresses...
Nontheless, this is not really efficient use of ressources since 3 of the 8 block RAMs will never be used.
I tried to check if the address at the input is larger than `DATADEPTH` and then assign don't cares for the data, but that results in the whole ram being implemented as distributed RAM / LUTRAM.
Am I missing something important or do I have to use one big ugly generate for this?

Comment: Try using natural not SLV for the address type. It may well be the conv_integer (which is non-standard anyway) that is forcing synth to be over-cautious.

Comment: The reason I use slv here is that this is part of a mixed Verilog/VHDL project. By convention we do not use other types on interfaces than slv and integer to avoid typing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of separate address bus width (ADDRWIDTH) and number of RAM
entries (DATADEPTH) is fine, and would give the synthesis tool freedom to
implement the design without using more RAM bits than required.

The reason that you may see more RAM bits used than minimum required, is that
the synthesis tool may choose an implementation that uses more internal RAM
primitives than the absolute minimum, which will usually occur if the there are
plenty of free RAM primitives or if so required in order to close timing.

If you try to experiment with the settings of DATAWIDTH, DATADEPTH, and
ADDRWIDTH, you will see that the synthesis tool does indeed use fewer internal
RAM primitives than what a simple rounding up of DATADEPTH to new 2 ** N would
require.

Using DATAWIDTH = 72, DATADEPTH = 17 * 1024, and ADDRWIDTH = 16 requires a
minimum of 72 * 17 Kib = 1224 Kib.  In one synthesis trial, this can fit into
76 RAMB16 of a Spartan6, thus total of 76 * 18 Kib = 1368 Kib.  Figure from
synthesis is below.

[image]

If DATADEPTH was rounded to nearest 2 * boundary it would be 32 * 1024, thus 
requiring 72 * 32 Kib = 2304 Kib.  So the Xilinx synthesis tool does make an 
intelligent fit.

By the way then a signal should be used for RAM, and not a shared variable,
since I expect that a shared variable may cause problems in some synthesis
tools.

Suggestion for code, including use clauses:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
  generic (
    DATAWIDTH : positive := 72;
    DATADEPTH : positive := 17 * 1024;
    ADDRWIDTH : positive := 16
    );
  port (
    clk_a  : in  std_logic;
    we_a   : in  std_logic;
    addr_a : in  std_logic_vector(ADDRWIDTH-1 downto 0);
    di_a   : in  std_logic_vector(DATAWIDTH-1 downto 0);
    do_a   : out std_logic_vector(DATAWIDTH-1 downto 0)
    );
end foo;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

architecture bar of foo is
  type myram_type is array (DATADEPTH-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(DATAWIDTH-1 downto 0);  --! type for ram content
  signal myram : myram_type;                                                                  --! ram
begin
  process (clk_a)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk_a) then
      if we_a = '1' then
        myram(conv_integer(addr_a)) <= di_a;
      end if;
      do_a <= myram(conv_integer(addr_a));
    end if;
  end process;
end bar;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your observations and the suggested code! I'll give it a shot asap.